# The cofinality of a linear order is regular

Tags: set-theory

Suppose that $\mathbb L = (L, \preccurlyeq)$ is a linear order. Let $\kappa = \text{cf}( \mathbb L)$ i.e. whenever $C \subseteq \mathbb L$ is cofinal then $|C| \geq \kappa$. I've been told that $\kappa$ must be a regular cardinal and to see this it helps to look at an obtainable well-ordering from $\mathbb L$, but I am not sure how to do so. Any ideas?

Comment: Suppose $\kappa$ is singular. This means there's a particular type of sequence in $\kappa$; do you see how to turn that into a sequence in $\mathbb{L}$ contradicting the assumption that $cf(\mathbb{L})=\kappa$? (Note that your definition is incomplete: $\kappa$ is the *least* such that every cofinal subset has size at least $\kappa$, or equivalently the smallest size of a cofinal subset.)

Comment: Hi Noah, thanks for the comment. I'm a little unsure of how to use the fact that $\mathbb L$ is a linear order? I have that if $\kappa = \text{cf}(\mathbb L)$ is singular with $\xi = \text{cf}(\kappa) < \kappa$ then we can combine cofinal functions to get a sequence $\left<C_{f(i)} \colon i < \xi\right>$ and $f\colon \xi \to \kappa$ is a cofinal function. If $C = \{C_\alpha \colon \alpha < \kappa\}$ is a cofinal subset of $\mathbb L$ then is this new sequence cofinal in $\mathbb L$ since $\sup (C_{f(i)})_{i < \xi} = \sup(C_\alpha)_{\alpha < \kappa} = L$?